# List of Figures - No "Figure" before subfigure number, but in front of figure

Tags: tocloft

In my list of figures I do not want the word "Figure" in front of my subfigures. Additionally, I would like to to have the numbering of the subfigure in brackets (so "(a)" instead of "a") in my list of figures and also directly under the "S" of the "SuperTest" Figure in the list of figures.

Thank you very much in advance!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,tabularx,graphicx}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=8pt,position=bottom,font=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=bf}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}

%%%%%%%%%%%% ToC, LoF, LoT ADJUSTMENTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Formatting ToC
% Adjust spacing between number and title in ToC

% Adjust dots in ToC, LoF, LoT
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{1}
\makeatother

\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from figures in lof
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from tables in lot

% Formatting LoF
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cftfigfont{\bfseries}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand\cftsubtabdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\newcommand\cftsubfigfont{\normalfont}
\newcommand\cftsubfigpresnum{}
\newcommand\cftsubfigaftersnum{}
\newcommand\cftsubfigaftersnumb{}
\newcommand\cftsubfigleader{\hfill}
\newcommand\cftsubfigpagefont{\normalfont}
\newcommand\cftsubfigafterpnum{}
\providecommand{\toclevel@subfigure}{1}
\renewcommand*\l@subfigure[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@lofdepth > \toclevel@subfigure
    \vskip \cftbeforesubfigskip
    {\leftskip \cftsubfigindent\relax
     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent \cftsubfigindent\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima \cftsubfignumwidth\relax
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftsubfigpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftsubfigaftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftsubfigaftersnumb
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {\cftsubfigfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftsubfigfillnum{#2}}%
  \fi
  }%
\newlength\cftbeforesubfigskip
  \setlength\cftbeforesubfigskip{\z@ \@plus.2\p@}
\newlength\cftsubfigindent
  \setlength\cftsubfigindent{3.8em}
\newlength\cftsubfignumwidth
  \setlength\cftsubfignumwidth{2.5em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubfigfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftsubfigleader\hfill}\par
}
\makeatother

% Formatting LoT
\setcounter{lotdepth}{1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cfttabfont{\bfseries}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
}
%\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\clearpage
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoftables
}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}

\clearpage

\section{Nice0}
\begin{figure}[htb] \label{figure:Test}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=8pt,position=bottom}
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\subcaption[Test]{Test}}\hfill
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\subcaption[Test2]{Test2}}
    \caption[SuperTest]{{\bf Test} \\Histogram of (a) Test and (b) most common Test sample.}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\section{Nice1}

\begin{table}[htbp]\label{table:Test}
\caption[Test]{Test} \blindtext
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|} \hline\hline
Ice Cream Store & Location & How to Get There \\ \hline
Toscanini’s & Central Square & Just walk! \\
Herrell’s & Harvard Square & Red Line \\
J.P. Licks & Davis Square & Red Line \\
Ben \& Jerry’s & Newbury Street & Green Line \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the brackets around the subfigure letters your can define your own listformat with

```
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{myListFormat}{(#2)}
```

and use it in defining the subcaption package like

```
\usepackage[list=true, listformat=myListFormat]{subcaption}
```

When you don't want the "Figure" prefix in front of the subfigures your should replace the part

```
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
```

of your code with

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure~}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5em}
```

I added a fully working modified example of your code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext,tabularx,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionListFormat{myListFormat}{(#2)}

\usepackage[list=true, listformat=myListFormat]{subcaption}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=8pt,position=bottom,font=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=bf}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}

%%%%%%%%%%%% ToC, LoF, LoT ADJUSTMENTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Formatting ToC
% Adjust spacing between number and title in ToC

% Adjust dots in ToC, LoF, LoT
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{1}
\makeatother

\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from figures in lof
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from tables in lot

% Formatting LoF
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cftfigfont{\bfseries}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand\cftsubtabdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\newcommand\cftsubfigfont{\normalfont}
\newcommand\cftsubfigpresnum{}
\newcommand\cftsubfigaftersnum{}
\newcommand\cftsubfigaftersnumb{}
\newcommand\cftsubfigleader{\hfill}
\newcommand\cftsubfigpagefont{\normalfont}
\newcommand\cftsubfigafterpnum{}
\providecommand{\toclevel@subfigure}{1}
\renewcommand*\l@subfigure[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@lofdepth > \toclevel@subfigure
    \vskip \cftbeforesubfigskip
    {\leftskip \cftsubfigindent\relax
     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent \cftsubfigindent\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima \cftsubfignumwidth\relax
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftsubfigpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftsubfigaftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftsubfigaftersnumb
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {\cftsubfigfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftsubfigfillnum{#2}}%
  \fi
  }%
\newlength\cftbeforesubfigskip
  \setlength\cftbeforesubfigskip{\z@ \@plus.2\p@}
\newlength\cftsubfigindent
  \setlength\cftsubfigindent{3.8em}
\newlength\cftsubfignumwidth
  \setlength\cftsubfignumwidth{2.5em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubfigfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftsubfigleader\hfill}\par
}
\makeatother

% Formatting LoT
\setcounter{lotdepth}{1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cfttabfont{\bfseries}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
{%
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure~}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5em}
\listoffigures%
}
%\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\clearpage
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoftables
}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}

\clearpage

\section{Nice0}
\begin{figure}[htb] \label{figure:Test}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=8pt,position=bottom}
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\subcaption[Test]{Test}}\hfill
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\subcaption[Test2]{Test2}}
    \caption[SuperTest]{{\bf Test} \\Histogram of (a) Test and (b) most common Test sample.}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\section{Nice1}

\begin{table}[htbp]\label{table:Test}
\caption[Test]{Test} \blindtext
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|} \hline\hline
Ice Cream Store & Location & How to Get There \\ \hline
Toscanini’s & Central Square & Just walk! \\
Herrell’s & Harvard Square & Red Line \\
J.P. Licks & Davis Square & Red Line \\
Ben \& Jerry’s & Newbury Street & Green Line \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions helped a lot. Question answered! @enco909